# Happy birthday dear (person's name)?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When you sing the happy birthday song, do you say

happy birthday dear (person's name)

or

happy birthday (person's name)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking whether a word can be omitted in singing a traditional song, which is a matter of opinion, and being song lyrics, is not dependent on conventional English grammar or usage to begin with.

Comment: Given that when I was learning foreign languages at school, they always had us learn to sing "happy birthday" in that language, I can understand why a learner would want to know about this.

Comment: @choster Well, you can explain exactly that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dear to fit the traditional tune of the song, otherwise it's missing a note. Additionally, the most commonly used version you hear in America has dear in it, even if it makes the song awkward.

> Happy birthday to you, happy birthday to you, happy birthday dear (name), happy birthday to you.

Comment: Well that's debatable. How about "Happy birthday Alexander"? Stuffing "dear" in there makes things very awkward.

Comment: I've sung the birthday song hundreds of times. That's how the song goes. Usually the lyric just gets a little awkward if their name doesn't fit, but they still use dear, and since you downvoted I will provide proof: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Birthday_to_You a quick Google search verifies what I'm saying.

Comment: In my experience, you always sing "Dear ______" even if it makes things very awkward.

Comment: @Element115: Well, no, it really doesn't prove anything of the kind, since it claims no such thing: the article just isn't that specific. (It does, of course, mention the *normal* pattern with "dear" in it. It does not claim that this must and shall always be sung even with three-, four-, or five-syllable names. That would be an extrapolation, and one that I specifically denied as valid.)

Comment: Please do your research before coming back here. It's really easy to use Google and see that this song is a **FORMERLY COPYRIGHTED SONG** and the lyrics in the copyright filing have *dear in them*. You can sing it however you want but that doesn't make it right.

Comment: A  US court held "The 1935 copyright held by Warner/Chappell applied only to a specific piano arrangement of the song, not the lyrics or melody."  Traditional songs tend to have many variations, and someone copyrighting a particular version doesn't make one variation more correct, it just makes that version more expensive to sing in public. Nathan is giving you feedback that can help you improve your answer. If  "dear" MUST be sung, you should edit your answer to make that clear and explain why. Folks can't reverse their DV unless the post is edited even if they are convinced by your comments.

Comment: I edited my answer to answer to clarify what I meant. I just think that mentioning the version that's used almost ubiquitously is the correct answer because you can't possible include everyone's variations. Anyone can change a song anyway they want.

Comment: @Element115: While it's certainly true that anyone can change a song however they want, it's also rather surprisingly common for groups to develop their own ideas of what is and is not common in the wider world. Without actual citations that support the relative frequency of different variations, all this answer has at present is "everyone I know sings it like X". But everyone *I* know sings it like Y. So who's really right about which is more common? I don't know, and I don't think you do either. Perhaps the variations are of similar popularity.

Answer (score 1):

You may or may not use *dear*, as necessary to fit (or as nearly as possible fit) the metre. If a person has one or two syllables in their name, you need the extra syllable to fit. If a person has four or more, it would make it more difficult to fit the metre. However, some are so much in the habit of using *dear* that they use it even for longer names.